# Android onRequestPermissionsResult method, granResults method come empty

Tags: android, security, permissions

I am developing android app and i want write event in Calendar Android.

I run app in Android Emulator with API 26.

I am calling ActivityCompat.requestPermissions method but in response **grandResults** parameter is empty. 
RequestCode parameter is correctly.

This is my code. I am calling this method to request permission:

```
public void PermisoEscribirCalendario()
    {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR)) {

                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR}, 123);
                }

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR},
                        1234);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }
    }
```

And response code on callback:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1234: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.

                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
```

And I show with an image, how grandResult parameter is empty when come to callback:

[image]

I hope you can help me.

Thanks you so much!

Comment: Can you explain what is your problem?

Comment: Why are you adding two permission requests? Remove the second `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` and change the first's code to 1234.

Comment: Thanks @SubrataM. Its the problem, the is duplicated and android studio make something wrong... Thanks so much